# Adding properties stored inside Iterator as siblings outside Iterator

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I have a requirement where I am preparing some payload inside Iterator and storing in to a property.
Now I want to read the payload which is stored inside property and build some response by adding the property values as siblings.

````
<iterate expression="//result" id="Results">
  <property name="test1" expression="//test1" />
  <property name="test2" expression="//test2" />
  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
     <format>[{     "test1":"$1",
                      "test2":"$2"
       }]</format>
     <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('test1')" />
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('test2')" />
     </args>
  </payloadFactory>
  <property name="ITERATOR_DATA_PAYLOAD" expression="$body" scope="operation" type="OM" />
</iterate>```

Enrich here all the ITERATOR_DATA_PAYLOAD property values here something like below by adding as siblings

```[{ "test1":"$1","test2":"$2"},{"test1":"$1","test2":"$2"},{ "test1":"$1","test2":"$2"},{"test1":"$1","test2":"$2"}]```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the response of each iterate into a single body, you have to use the Aggregate mediator as well, provided you're calling an endpoint.

To aggregate the response, you have to do it in the outSequence of the API/Service where you have to provide loopback inside the Iterate, at the end.

PFB for a sample API.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Iterate" context="/iterate">
   <resource methods="POST">
      <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name=":: PAYLOAD ::" expression="$body"/>
         </log>
         <iterate continueParent="true" id="Results" preservePayload="true" expression="//result" sequential="true">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="test1" expression="//test1"/>
                  <property name="test2" expression="//test2"/>
                  <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                     <format>{"test1":"$1","test2":"$2"}</format>
                     <args>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('test1')"/>
                        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('test2')"/>
                     </args>
                  </payloadFactory>
                  <log>
                     <property name=":: Iterated PAYLOAD ::" expression="$body"/>
                  </log>
                  <property name="ITERATOR_DATA_PAYLOAD" expression="$body" scope="operation" type="OM"/>
                  <call>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:8280/echoAPI"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </call>
                  <log>
                     <property name=":: Echo Response ::" expression="$body"/>
                  </log>
                  <loopback/>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <property name="response" scope="default">
                <Responses/>
            </property>
            <aggregate id="Results">
                <completeCondition>
                    <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                </completeCondition>
                <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="response" expression="$body/*[1]">
                    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
                    <respond/>
                </onComplete>
            </aggregate>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Request :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "test1": "test1",
            "test2": "test2"
        },
        {
            "test1": "test3",
            "test2": "test4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Response :

```
{
    "Responses": [
        {
            "test1": "test1",
            "test2": "test2"
        },
        {
            "test1": "test3",
            "test2": "test4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, I have used an echo API, which will send the same request as the response. For your use case, you can use your actual endpoint.

This is how iterate & aggregate work together in WSO2 EI/ESB.

Comment: Hi Prabakaran, Thank you for the response. I am able to read the property outside but the problem is when I am adding each property value as sibling and building the payload as I mentioned, it's only giving me one records. It's not adding all the iterated records as siblings.

Comment: Hi Tejas, I have updated the answer as per your query.  @TejasChinthakindi